# Compilation error: package javax.ejb and javax.mail does not exist using IBM SDK 7

Tags: java, ibm-jdk

Recently I have updated `IBM SDK 6` to `IBM SDK 7` but getting error as

```
 package javax.ejb does not exist
 package javax.mail does not exist
```

so do I need to download and place those jar? Does `IBM SDK 7` supports `EJB2.5`

Comment: Those packages are not part of SE 6 or 7.   I don't think they were part of the IBM JDK.  You probably had included them somewhere else in your environment, on your CLASSPATH or extdirs or somewhere.     Maybe it would help to add more context as to what you're doing and how you're coming across this werror.

Answer (score 0):

The packages you listed are part of Java EE (Enterprise Edition). The IBM SDK for Java supplies Java SE (Standard Edition), which Java EE runs on top of. To get the javax.ejb and javax.mail classes, you will need to install a Java EE implementation.